# quotes when using str.format in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

When using `str.format` to output in python 2.7.6 such as below:

```
>>> "| {0: ^18} | {1: ^18} |".format(1, 0.001)
```

This results:

```
'|         1          |       0.001        |'
```

I am wondering how to suppress the single quotes on either end of the output string.

Comment: You mean `str.format`, not `sys.format`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes are not part of the return value of the format statement, they are coming from the python interpreter, telling you that it is showing you a string value:

```
momerath:~ mgregory$ python
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "| {0: ^18} | {1: ^18} |".format(1, 0.001)
'|         1          |       0.001        |'
>>> print "| {0: ^18} | {1: ^18} |".format(1, 0.001)
|         1          |       0.001        |
>>> a = 1
>>> a
1
>>> a = "foo"
>>> a
'foo'
>>> print a
foo
>>>
```

... so if you want to see only the value of a string, simply print it.

I'm not aware of a way to ask the python interpreter not to quote string results when it reports them.

Comment: Thank you GreenAsJade. I didn't realise that the result wasn't directed to the output.

Answer (score 2):

Rising to the challenge of GreenAsJade, and another attempt at directly answering the question by monkey-patching a subclass of `str` that will echo the **str** representation on the REPL.

```
class SillyString(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Instantiate the string:

```
>>> foo = SillyString('foo')
```

And have it echoed on the Python shell:

```
>>> foo
foo
```

contrasted with the standard Python str:

```
>>> 'foo'
'foo'
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think that the reason why you can't monkey patch a an "instantiated string is because it is immutable".  In fact, you don't monkey patch instances, you monkey patch classes.   I can't find a way to monkey patch a str because it is _built in_.   Nice silly string though :)

Comment: I guess it's more that it's implemented as a builtin in C. Good point, I'll modify my comments.

Answer (score 1):

GreenAsJade has a good answer (+1), but I'll see if I can improve on it.

The interpreter is merely echoing the literal in the REPL by printing the `__repr__` of the object, a string which if printed should show an unambiguous representation of the object. So to remove the end quotes (and thus the unambiguous object representation), print the object:

```
>>> ['foo'].__repr__()
"['foo']"

>>> 'foo'.__repr__()
"'foo'"

>>> print 'foo'.__repr__()
'foo'

>>> print 'foo'
foo
```

Comment: Nice observation.  To really nail it with this thinking, you should show how to monkey-patch the __repr__() of a string.   That would truly answer the OP's question "how can I stop python from doing this" ;)  (I get "cant set attributes of built-in type str")